# Windows 7 Navigation Bar — show only plain favourites?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, favorites, navigation

Is there a method to force Windows 7 show only plain list of favourites every time a new Explorer window is open?

I love the way it was previously done in Vista (no tree, no root item):

[image: http://files.rsdn.ru/4162/explorer.png]